# Can you use "@" sign when publishing to your Facebook wall via Open Graph API?

Tags: api, facebook, facebook-opengraph

Quick question. I have a site that publishes user activities back to their wall using Open Graph API. I was wondering if I can use the "@" sign for mentioning user's friends in the message that I want to publish.

If yes, how would I go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No you cannot**, that is only available on the native Facebook site via a JavaScript call. You cannot do this with api calls

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it on the wall, however you can do it when publishing stories to the app dashboard with the syntax @:USER_ID